# scipy univariant spline: how to solve for x given y

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

say i've fit x and y datapoints to a scipy.interpolate.univariant spline under python3.  and i've plotted the spline against the raw datapoints and its a good fit.

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline, sproot
 f1 = UnivariateSpline(x, y, k=3, s=0.085)
```

where x and y are python lists.

say the y range is from 1 to 13.  how do i solve for x of the spline given a y = 7?  i've tried sproot and others but i'm not sure how to proceed or the syntax and functions.

thank you in advance, lucas

Answer (score 0):

Interpolate x vs y and evaluate the result.